# How to map Ctrl-[ to escape key in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to map Ctrl-[ as if it is the Escape key.

Is it possible in VSCode?

I don't want manually map Ctrl-[ to all the potential commands that are mapped by the Escape key.